# control the mouse

Tags: mouse, remote

lets see if somebody can give me ideas
I want to make the cursor automatically select ten different areas of the browser, and then read and save a small text which
 will appear every time(maybe on excel)
thanks for your time

Comment: ok, more details, never thought will have many answers and that fast...       what i want to do is as this: have 10 buttons in a screen, so, sequentially, push one behind the other, every time i push a button, three different texts will show in the same screen, i have to recognize , read and save in an excel or db that three data together with a timestamp( the text will be always in the same place but different texts for every time i push the button)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that could be accomplished with xdotool. You'll need to create a bash script that uses `xdotool mousemove` and click, likely in the following form:

`xdotool mousemove [x location] [y location] click [mouse button, 1 for left click]`

You can use some looping and conditional logic, and if you want to use relative mouse movement you should be able to replace `xdotool mousemove` with `mousemove_relative`

Answer (score 0):

[Actiona](https://wiki.actiona.tools/doku.php) is a task automation tool. You can set actions for the mouse, keyboard, find an image in the screen and many more in a user friendly way.

```
sudo apt install actiona
```